# drupal commerce product type limit

Tags: commerce

we are about to build an ecommerce webiste using drupal commerce, we are going to take product list from semantic3 and we found that it has like 70 milion product list and 10 bilion sales offer .. will drupal commerce support that amount .. and what do your recommend ... and is there a better way for import ..

Thanks

Comment: Note: You mean product entity, not product type in this case. Also, the actual question here isn't on Drupal Commerce, but rather Drupal handling this amount of data. With this amount of data you'll need to consider certain engineering techniques.

I recommend reformatting this question around those aspects to get some better insight

Comment: actually drupal commerce handling contents more different than the normal way of drupal .. so it's better to put in mind the amount of data .. yeh there will be some engineering rework .. that's why i am asking if some one had pass through some experience in this way, or have a clear vision in the way of implementation .. or Drupal itself will not support that ..